# move mdadm raid to new system

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm

Have a 4-drive Ubuntu mdadm raid in a system whose motherboard (ASUS N1996) failed permanently.

I tried putting the 4 drives in another system with a different motherboard, but when it came up it only saw one drive and I think it ran a filesystem check, which I read here might've deleted the superblocks: here https://askubuntu.com/questions/69086/mdadm-superblock-recovery

It boots into a degraded raid and the md2 array is not active

There are no /dev/sd* links at all, which I don't understand, The motherboard has 3 bios options: IDE, AHCI, and RAID

mdadm shows only one active drive if I boot in IDE mode (which was the initial state when I booted up).  If I boot in the other 2 modes (at this point anyway) it dumps me to a shell.

the one drive appears as hda and has 3 partitions.

At this point I'm unsure how to proceed. I hope it's still recoverable but I've been reading a bunch of different solutions out there, and the fact no /dev/sd links are here make me wonder what's going on.

I'll try to add more info once I'm back at the system, but wanted to ask for any advice about why the /dev/sd links are missing in the meanwhile.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Moving mdadm raids to another system should not be a problem. Your problem comes before mdadm is in the picture, the disks are not being detected. Check /proc/partitions to see what disks & partitions _are_ being recognized.

Comment: thanks wurtel - currently i'm cloning the drives so as to experiment on the copies and keep the originals in their present state.  will update later, thanks again.

Comment: Good news - we hooked the drives up to a different system that happens to have the same mother board model as the original (ASUS N1996) and they show up as /dev/sd[abcd] & raid works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Solved - we first cloned all 4 drives so we are working with copies and preserving the originals in the current state.  hooked the copy drives up to a different system that happens to have the same mother board model as the original (ASUS N1996) and they show up as /dev/sd[abcd] & raid now works fine!

This was a really old Ubuntu 6 system that hadn't been updated in forever and I suspect didn't have the drivers needed for the newer motherboard.